# Adjust input width if value is greater than... (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to adjust the input width of a form if the value (character count) is greater than a certain amount.

```
<input id="search-typing" type="text" name="keyword" autofocus="true" >

$(function(){
    var myLength = $("#search-typing").val().length;     
    if (myLength >= 4) {
        $("#search-typing").css("width", "200px");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wkEMK/21/

Comment: You might want to bind it to some event like http://jsfiddle.net/7MwzG/ or http://jsfiddle.net/5HE6j/

Comment: ^ Thank you. Answered in less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

bind to the keyup event

```
$(function(){
  $("#search-typing").keyup(function(){
    var myLength = $("#search-typing").val().length;     
    if (myLength >= 4) {
        $("#search-typing").css("width", "200px");
    }
  });
});
```